# Draggable Element does not work on Touch Screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a draggable div that works in computer very well but today I checked in touch screen and knew that it does not move.
The JavaScript code I have uses `onmousemove`, is there any alternative for that on **touchscreen**?
What to do to solve this? BTW, I'd like this to work on both touch screen and desktop devices.

Currently what I have:

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;

    let parentElement = elmnt.parentElement;
    if (elmnt.offsetTop < 0) {
      elmnt.style.top = "0px";
      return;
    }
    if (elmnt.offsetTop > (parentElement.offsetHeight - elmnt.offsetHeight) - 2) {
      elmnt.style.top = (parentElement.offsetHeight - elmnt.offsetHeight - 2) + "px";
      return;
    }
    if (elmnt.offsetLeft < 0) {
      elmnt.style.left = "0px";
      return
    }
    if (elmnt.offsetLeft > (parentElement.offsetWidth - elmnt.offsetWidth) - 2) {
      elmnt.style.left = (parentElement.offsetWidth - elmnt.offsetWidth - 2) + "px";
      return;
    }

    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="border: 0.1vw solid gray;">
  <div id="mydiv">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/287">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not test it, but if you are open to use other methods (like using jQuery) [jQuery ui draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) can be a good option.

Comment: @hamid-davodi There's no jQuery in the provided tags. And no. You don't need jQuery.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan I just suggest **another** method other than writing codes with js that could solve the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] to create a [mcve].

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan if you mean to minimize my codes to be more understandable, unfortunately I can not minimize that javascript, It does not have any extra text.

Comment: *"I have a draggable div that works in computer"*, but the code you gave doesn't even work on a computer!

Comment: @Neptotech-vishnu It works great on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

### For mobile phones instead of mouse events, you should use touch events.

That means that instead of `onmousemove` you should use `ontouchmove` and `ontouchstart`, `ontouchstart` accordingly.
Touch events don't have direct access to `clientX` and `clientY` properties, you can retrieve them only from `Touch` that is retrievable from the list `TouchesEvent.touches`. This list contains the number of touches to the screen that were happening when a listener was invoked.

Also, I would recommend adding listeners instead of assigning handlers, because they are considered experimental for touch events.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) is more detailed information on how to use Touch Events.